# Is data of classes with constexpr constructor put into ROM?

Tags: c++, embedded

If I have a POD like

```
struct Configuration {
public:
    constexpr Configuration(Interface& iface, Interface& iface2, Interface& iface3):iface_(iface),iface2_(iface2),iface3_(iface3) {}
    
    Interface& iface_;
    Interface& iface2_;
    Interface& iface3_;
};
```

and instantiate the class like this:

```
constexpr Configuration conf{cl, cl, cl};
```

Can I be sure, that those 3 references are put into ROM? Or only that the constructor is called during compile time, but the data still will be put into RAM? Or is this completely compiler dependent? The current target system is an ARM controller without OS and the compiler is GCC/IAR.

Comment: This is compiler or system dependent, for sure. You might have to look into the map file that the linker can generate. Please [edit] your question and add the target system and compiler you use.

Comment: Here's a little piece of research that might help your question: Check what the [C++ memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model) has to say about "RAM" and "ROM". (Hint: why should C++ require that every device has ROM?)

Comment: Also, your type can't be POD because it contains references. But the POD concept is deprecated in favor of the _trivial type_ and _standard-layout type_ concepts anyway. In this case the class is _trivially-copyable_, but neither _trivial_, nor _standard-layout_, because of the lack of default constructor and the presence of reference members respectively.

Comment: If it is only used at compile time a constexpr function is not required to end up in memory at all. (same for constructors). If the function is also used at runtime it is compiled and linked like any other function.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to work with C++ in embedded systems without continuously disassembling and also checking the map file. Any oddball, poorly-defined feature might decide to do turn into wild and crazy things in the binary, like for example ending up in RAM just for the heck of it, or that some trash library is reaching for heap allocation between the lines. So it will be hard to stay productive since you can't really trust the language or compiler to do what you want. A typical C++ problem is that it silently spews default constructor calls into the time-sensitive CRT start-up code.

Comment: Yes, thats what I also observed. I checked the map file for the IAR artifacts and it showed me that the data is placed in ROM. However compiling with gcc x64 the executable shows me the data is stored in RAM and ROM (maybe to initialize it from ROM). I hoped for a general concept on how to store data in ROM across multiple compilers without using pragmas.